# Verificação de categoria em uso C#/ASPX

Tags: c#

Bom dia,

Estou a tentar validar uma situação que passo a explicar, por exemplo adicionamos uma categoria "Diversos", e essa mesma categoria é usada no produto "Chaves", imaginemos que vamos apagar a categoria "Peças", o produto "Chaves" com categoria "Diversos" permanece.

O que eu quero de facto validar é se vamos apagar uma categoria, verificar se essa mesma categoria não está em uso em algum produto.

O que eu tentei foi o seguinte na Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT Categoria FROM Categorias WHERE (Categoria) NOT IN (SELECT Categoria FROM Produtos);
```

Código C#:

```
        if (BLL.BD.backoffice.VerificaCatgProdutoUso(Categoria).Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            lblCatgsInfo.Text = "Categoria " + Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[1].Text) + " em uso num determinado produto, tente de novo";
            lblCatgsInfo.Visible = true;
            lblCatgsInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        if (BLL.BD.backoffice.VerificaCatgProdutoUso(Categoria).Rows.Count != 1)
        {
            int resultado = BLL.BD.backoffice.EliminarCatgProduto(IDCatg);
            lblCatgsInfo.Text = "A categoria " + Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[1].Text) + " com o ID " + Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Text) + " foi eliminada com sucesso!";
            lblCatgsInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblCatgsInfo.Visible = true;
            GridViewManage.DataBind();

        }
```

Contudo não está a funcionar, alguém me pode informar o que está incorrecto?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: não entendi muito bem, mas será que a categoria não está sendo utilizada como FK? Se for isso, deves deletar de forma cascateada. Também fiquei sem entender o que você disse que tentou na SP. Eu vi apenas um select e não um delete. Experimentou colocar um BP no seu método: EliminarCatgProduto(IDCatg) para ver o que acontece? Se realmente está chamando o delete ou não.

Comment: Eu apenas quero que a stored procedure faça a verificação se a categoria "peças", de facto está a ser utilizada por algum produto.

Se a categoria "peças" existir na coluna "categoria" da tabela "produtos", queria que ele validasse o erro de forma a não deixar apagar a categoria, pelo facto de estar a ser utilizada por um produto.

Caso não esteja a ser utilizada, poderá ser efectuado o DELETE, isso está tudo funcional, o que de facto necessito é da validação da categoria em uso pelo produto

Comment: Pelo que vi faltou a você comparar a categoria da table categoria da categoria da table produtos. Editei minha resposta. Lá dá para você adaptar o que você quer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not In quebra a performance de qualquer BD. Faça a query inversa, com IN ou Exists e não Not In. Se você fizesse isso: `SELECT Categoria FROM Produtos where Categoria = @Categoria`. Se retornar NULL, aí você saberia que aquela categoria não está sendo utilizada em produtos e você faria o que deveria fazer. Se que eu entendi a pergunta faria isso. Essa seria sua validação.

Uma delete direto e depois uma atualização no GridView na SP, não seria ideal, tipo:

```
delete from categoria where not exists(SELECT Categoria FROM Produtos where categoria.categoria = produtos.categoria)
```

Isso tudo dentro da sua SP e depois um refresh em seu GridView para atualizar as alterações. Isso te ajuda?

Comment: Creio que dessa maneira não irá resultar, pois a stored procedure não faz a verificação de ambas as tabelas categorias (coluna categoria) e produtos (coluna categoria).

Comment: entendi mal. Achei que o que era necessário era apenas o que estava em produtos. Vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, fico a aguardar.

Comment: Assim nessa forma irá apagar todas as categorias, falta algo do tipo IDCatg = @IDCatg

Comment: Como falei, é ir adaptando à sua necessidade. Não conheço seu projeto no todo, aí é só ir passando parâmetros para ter a certeza que é somente  aquilo que você quer. Um ID, uma outra informação. O que passei foi puramente genérico e hipotético.

Comment: Falta algo do tipo WHERE IDCatg = @IDCatg para apenas apagar a categoria seleccionada.

Nesse caso como seria?

Comment: Nesta situação no final da query fica "AND IDCatg = @IDCatg", ainda estou a fazer os testes mas parece-me que está de forma correta dessa maneira.

Comment: Vai fundo que vai dar certo, pode acreditar. Não vejo outra maneira pelo que eu entendi.